# Get series of counts with conditions using ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm displaying a graph of `Subscription` counts that may have been `soft_destroyed_at` at some point.

To do this I run a query for each month which is of course not as good as one big honking query but my SQL skills fail me once again.

Here's how I do it in Ruby:

```
months = (0..12).map { |i| i.months.ago.end_of_month }

stats = Hash[months.map do |eom|
  [
    eom.beginning_of_month.to_date,
    Subscription.where(
      'created_at < ?' \
      'AND (soft_destroyed_at IS NULL ' \
      '  OR soft_destroyed_at > ?) ' \
      'AND (suspended_at IS NULL ' \
      '  OR suspended_at > ?)',
      eom, eom, eom
    ).count
  ]
end]

# => { 2018-04-01 => 10, 2018-03-01 => 15, ... }
```

How could I write this as one query using ActiveRecord – or if necessary using *raw* SQL>

The database is Postgres 10.2, the app is Rails 5.2.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll give this a shot in a while, if no-one beats me to it, but basically this can be done with a `group_by` with the rounded month, then counting.

Comment: Something like: `select("date_trunc('month', soft_destroyed_at) as month").group("month").count` ... I haven't tried running it yet.

Comment: The syntax *might* vary depending on your database type, though - so you'd best specify that in the question.

Comment: It's Postgres of course! Updated the question :)

Comment: I toyed around with `group` and `select` but then it came to the `where`s and I gave up.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `soft_destroyed_at` is used. Here's one idea. It groups by the start of the month for `soft_destroyed_at`: 
 `Subscription.where(
  'soft_destroyed_at IS NULL OR created_at < soft_destroyed_at OR created_at < suspended_at'
).group("date_trunc('month', soft_destroyed_at)").count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query (I used 12 month in 2017; just change as you wish). This assumes a Postgresql DB, as you said in a comment:

```
query = 
  "select months.month, count(created_at) "\
  "from "\
    "(select DATE '2017-01-01'+(interval '1' month * generate_series(0,11)) as month, "\
            "DATE '2017-02-01'+(interval '1' month * generate_series(0,11)) as next) months "\
    "outer join subscriptions on "\
    "created_at < month and "\
    "(soft_destroyed_at IS NULL or soft_destroyed_at >= next) and "\
    "(suspended_at IS NULL OR suspended_at >= next) "\
  "group by month "\
  "order by month"

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

The first subquery (the `select` inside `from`) generates this:

```
month                 next
"2017-01-01 00:00:00";"2017-02-01 00:00:00"
"2017-02-01 00:00:00";"2017-03-01 00:00:00"
"2017-03-01 00:00:00";"2017-04-01 00:00:00"
"2017-04-01 00:00:00";"2017-05-01 00:00:00"
"2017-05-01 00:00:00";"2017-06-01 00:00:00"
"2017-06-01 00:00:00";"2017-07-01 00:00:00"
"2017-07-01 00:00:00";"2017-08-01 00:00:00"
"2017-08-01 00:00:00";"2017-09-01 00:00:00"
"2017-09-01 00:00:00";"2017-10-01 00:00:00"
"2017-10-01 00:00:00";"2017-11-01 00:00:00"
"2017-11-01 00:00:00";"2017-12-01 00:00:00"
"2017-12-01 00:00:00";"2018-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Next is only used to make it easier to check if the subscription was active at least until next month (destroyed or suspended are >= next (which guarantees the subscriber was active during current month).

Comment: `ERROR:  column "next" does not exist`

Comment: Kind of works! Only kink is that it skips zero values. If a given month has 0 matching rows it is completely omitted from the result.

Comment: You could change to an outer join instead. It should work I guess.

Comment: That includes the keys, but empty values are `1` instead of `0` 

Comment: Use count(created_at) instead of count(*)